# React native flash message "Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

Trying to showMessage if server returns error, this error is stored in context.

```
import { showMessage } from 'react-native-flash-message';

 const {
    createMission,
    state: { errorMessage },
    clearErrorMessage,
  } = useContext(MissionContext);

  if (errorMessage && errorMessage !== undefined) {
    showMessage({
      message: errorMessage,
      type: 'danger',
    });
  }
```

This doesn't work